# Setting up NetworkManager on Bookworm

Tags: networkmanager, raspberry-pi-os-bookworm

Since Bookworm RaspiOS is using NetworkManager by default and not dhcpcd5. Previously on Bullseye I had a set up with dhcpcd5 as follows:

```
# static IP configuration:
denyinterfaces wlan0

interface eth0
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1
metric 201

interface usb0
static ip_address=10.0.0.2/24
static routers=10.0.0.1
static domain_name_servers=10.0.0.1 8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1
metric 202

interface bnep0
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1
metric 203
```

Now with NetworkManager and Bookworm I have this in NetworkManager.conf with dhcpcd5 installed:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown
dhcp=dhcpcd

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

But I am wondering how would I set this up without dhcpcd5, or would you suggest just using dhcpcd5 with NetworkManager as I have now. Whatever works best ofcourse and is recommended.

Comment: You have listed something you don't use, haven't explained what you did, failed to explain your setup and haven't actually asked a question about what you want to do.

Comment: If you want a recommendation **just use Network Manager** - forget what you did in the past.